# NSLayoutConstraint - can't set subview frame to parent view bounds

Tags: ios, uiview, swift3, nslayoutconstraint

I have a testView `UIView` and subview named testViewSub. The testView is constrained by using `NSLayoutConstraint`. And i set subView frame to `testView.bounds`. But it doesn't work. Here is the code

```
let testView = UIView()
    testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    self.view.addSubview(testView)

    testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


    NSLayoutConstraint(item: testView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 30).isActive = true

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: testView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -30).isActive = true

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: testView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 200).isActive = true

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: testView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .height, multiplier: 0.15, constant: 0).isActive = true




    let testViewSub = UIView()
    testViewSub.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    testViewSub.frame = testView.bounds
    self.testView.addSubview(testViewSub)

    testViewSub.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

But if i set testView's frame using `CGRect`. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the layout happening? I've run into issues before where the constraints don't take effect until the view appears, so relying on frames to be the correct size in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` causes problems.

In this case, adding `testViewSub` in `viewDidAppear` worked for me, though I'm not sure it's the way I would recommend. Using constraints to lay it out, just as with `testView`, will also work from `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`:

```
    // layout constraints however you want - in this case they are such that green view's frame = red view's bounds

    let testViewSub = UIView()
    testViewSub.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    self.testView.addSubview(testViewSub)

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: testViewSub, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: testView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: testViewSub, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: testView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: testViewSub, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: testView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: testViewSub, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: testView, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true


    testViewSub.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

This will also deal with rotation better than simply setting the frame.